# Removing unused .lib files from Visual C++ build

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Does link.exe have a command line parameter, Visual Studio setting, or other technique to print out which specified library files were not actually needed to build the DLL or EXE?

I'm trying to trim down a project file (native c++) that has several dozen unnecessary .lib files specified as dependencies.  So far, I'm just removing each "one at a time" and rebuilding.  There's got to be a better way.  And I would suspect the linker would know if a library was actually used or not in the link of the output binary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `/VERBOSE:UNUSEDLIBS` option to the `LINK.EXE` command.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx

"/VERBOSE:UNUSEDLIBS - Displays information about any library files that are unused when the image is created."